# why Perl eval get errors

Tags: perl, eval

If I write this code:

```
for $i (1..3) { 
 $j = $i;
print $j;
}
```

it works.

And this code will work:

```
$code = "  
 for $i (1..3) { 
  #### $j = $i;
  print $j;
}  
eval $code
```

But if I try to write it like this:

```
$code = "
for $i (1..3) { 
$j = $i;
print $j;
 }  
eval $code
```

It will catch an error, why? who can help me?

Comment: is this your actual code? don't looks like second one is runnable

Comment: Never ever say "an error" without specifying *exactly* which error.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: and look at $@ to see what the error is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a quote :

```
$code = '
for $i (1..3) { 
    $j = $i;
    print $j;
}';
eval $code;
```

and 'single quotes' here are mandatory to not expand variables before the `eval` call.

Answer (score 9):

The second one works purely by accident. Your double-quoted string is interpolating empty values for `$i` and `$j` and you're actually running

```
for  (1..3) {
  ### = 
  print ;
}
```

which coincidentally works because `for` will assign to `$_` if you don't name a variable, and `print` will print `$_` by default. When you remove the comment marker, the lone equals sign causes a syntax error.

If you had used `strict` it would have prevented you from compiling the broken code in the first place, and if you had used `warnings` it would have at least warned you about the use of the uninitialized variables `$i` and `$j` in string interpolation.